# When I run npm run build I get this error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, deployment

I am pretty new to this and pretty lost as well. I believe I switched up a lot of things which has me facing this problem at the moment. Ultimately, I am just trying to `npm run build` my React.js project so I could deploy it. But I run `npm run build` and I see this error:

```
my-blog git:(main) ✗ npm run build
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/rondon/code/my-blog/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/rondon/code/my-blog/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/rondon/.npm/_logs/2022-01-22T05_37_12_010Z-debug.log
```

What I understood from this is that I need to make a package.json file so I did that in my "my-blog" directory by running `npm init`. Cool, I do that and now I have a new package.json file in "my-blog" and I manually put in a `"build": "react-scripts build"` so I can run `npm run build` without getting an error saying I am missing a build script. This is how that package.json file looks now:

```
{
  "name": "my-blog",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "react-scripts build"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/rmera1026/my-blog.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/rmera1026/my-blog/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/rmera1026/my-blog#readme"
}
```

I `npm run build` again and now get this:

```
my-blog git:(main) ✗ npm run build

> my-blog@1.0.0 build
> react-scripts build

sh: react-scripts: command not found
```

Lastly, I think I am having this problem because of how my file might be set up as well so [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEKIB.png) are how things are looking.

Answer (score 0):

Your `my-blog` project has 2 directories. One is `api`, another one is `client`.

You have to build in your `client` directory, but **you're outside of it**. Change your directory to `client` and run `npm run build`

```sh
cd client && npm run build
```

Comment: Would you happen to know if this will allow me to host and automatically deploy my application on GitHub while I have my project saved as "username".github.io in a git repository?

Comment: @rmera1026 You can follow this tutorial: https://dev.to/yuribenjamin/how-to-deploy-react-app-in-github-pages-2a1f